# do i need to upgrade my power supply after adding a new hdd drive?

Tags: hard-disk, power-supply, upgrade

I have a pc with this configuration and my power supply is 650W
do I need to upgrade my power supply if I add a Western Digital Blue 4TB Hard Disk Drive?

core i5 10400F,
Asus TUF 2060,
WD Blue 1TB,
SAMSUNG 970 Evo Plus,
16GB RAM,
B460m-a Motherboard,
A Green Z2+ hero case with 5 fans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, Only if you don't have SATA power ports free

Long answer, If you have not overclocked your PC and you put max load on it, it will use about 300W of power. This means there is still 350W PSU headroom. A typical SATA hard drive uses about 5-10W power if fully used, so you could in theory add 35 hard drives if power was the only constraint (which is not the case, since your motherboard has at most 6 SATA ports)

Answer (score 0):

adding the hard disk drive you mentioned, any hard disk drive for that matter, draws up to 5 watts and at idle is 3 watts.  you do not need to upgrade from an existing 650 watt power supply to accomodate an additional 5 watts.

https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/internal-drives/wd-blue-hdd/data-sheet-wd-blue-pc-hard-drives-2879-771436.pdf

if you are short on sata power connectors, amazon or ebay a molex to sata_power adapter: `Cable Matters 3-Pack 4 Pin Molex to SATA Power Cable (SATA to Molex) - 6 Inches` $7.

Comment: the WD black hdd's, the performance ones, draw a little more power than the blue, a whopping 10 watts.